# How to rapidly switch from one directory to another Python

Tags: python, directory, pickle

I have a huge list of image in one directory and another corresponding list of annotations in the other (.txt files).
I need to perform an operation on each image following the matching image annotations and save it into another directory. Is there an elegant way not to chdir three times at each step?
Maybe using cPickle or whatever library used for fast files management ?

```
import glob
from PIL import Image

os.chdir('path_images')
list_im=glob.glob('*.jpg')
list_im.sort()
list_im=path_images+list_im
os.chdir('path_txt')
list_annot=glob.glob('*.txt')
list_annot.sort()
list_annot=path_txt+list_im

for i in range(0,len(list_images)):
```

## Joel pointed out that the os operations are not mandatory if you include       the path in the name

```
   #os.chdir('path_images')
   im=Image.open(list_im[i])
   #os.chdir('path_text')
   action_on_image(im,list_annot[i])
   #os.chdir('path_to_save_image')
   im.save(path_to_save+nom_image)
```

I am a true beginner in Python but I am confident that my code is super inefficient and can be improved.

Comment: You may have missed that `paths` may not only contain the file basename, but also the path itseft ;-)  Have a look at `os.path.join()`

Comment: Ok so if I just modify directly list_im and list_annot to contain the whole path I do not have to use chdir is that what you are saying ?

Comment: I will modify my code and wait for an even faster implementation but thanks for your answer !

Comment: you can use full path and even `../../filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **don't** have to `chdir` (and FWIW you really don't want to depend on the current working directory). Use absolute paths everywhere in your code and you'll be fine.

```
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image

abs_images_path = <absolute path to your images directory here>
abs_txt_path = <absolute path to your txt directory here>
abs_dest_path = <absolute path to where you want to save your images>

list_im=sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(abs_images_path, '*.jpg')))
list_annot=sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(abs_txt_path, '*.txt')))

for im_path, txt_path in zip(list_im, list_annot):
   im = Image.open(im_path)
   action_on_image(im, txt_path)
   im.save(os.path.join(abs_dest_path, nom_image))
```

Note that if your paths are relative to  where your script is installed, you can get the script's directory path with `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

Comment: Thanks for this answer clean and precise !

Comment: I agree: avoid playing with `os.chdir()`, as this is not something you can rely on in your code, and may break other, badly-coded software.